# How to allow mysql to allow for same table names, just different letter case in windows

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, duplicates, case-sensitive

I have this mysql db, it has duplicate table names, just different lettercase.  So when importing these tables to my windows xampp setup through phpmyadmin, mysql just ignores the imports with same table names.  So I have these tables:

dealer
Dealer

I import dealer just fine, then when I import Dealer, mysql says table exists, and ignores the Dealer import all together.

Comment: why not just fix the db to make table names different?  This will keep on coming back and bite you over and over again.

Comment: so that's pretty much best option?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When starting mysql, you must set the system variable [lower_case_table_names](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_lower_case_table_names) to `0`.

On linux, , which uses a *case-sensitive* file system, you can do it.

On Windows, which uses a *case-insensitive* file system, you can not do it, because windows can not distinguish between the two cases.

See [this documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html) for details.

Comment: well the db im importing from does...its on a linux server, but it def has those two tables...